# API Gateway in Swift, what would be best practices with AWSModel

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I need to know what would be the best practice using the AWSModel class. The api is always returning me an AWSModel object, that's ok, but I need to know if I should use this objects in the whole app, or if it's better to create a new class in order to extend the custom functionality that the AWS class brings me? 
In the case I use the AWSModel objects, it's correct if I put custom variables or methods inside the class?
In short: it's a bad practice to modify the AWSModel class that APIGateway brings me?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model object's files are generated and would need to be re-generated if your models ever changed.

If you have custom variables that can only be populated on the client side, then it may be possible to include them in the model, but don't populate the variables on the server side.

For methods, you may go the route of extensions if you really need them to be part of the class.